# Gravitational waves and time

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, gravitational-waves

Two questions.

It is said that time can only go slower in gravity fields and if you move faster.

I have heard that when a gravitational wave pass earth then the space/time vibrate and time change for an instance.

But a wave is often with a top and a valley.

They have now atomic clocks that might be able to detect time variations, placed in satellites around the sun and "quantum entangled".
"Using Atomic Clocks to Detect Gravitational Waves"
http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00996

So what if we could compare time ticks between clocks in space at "absolute frame of reference" where time has its maximum universal speed as time in deep space between Galaxy Filaments.

Will we only detect that time ticks slower for an instance when the gravational wave pass?

**1. Or will we detect that time tick slower AND faster than normal time also, as compared to zero gravity time and no movement time in "absolute frame of reference"?**

**2. Can time go let's say 10 times faster by theory/mathematics, by a extreme theoretical gravitational wave, than time in "absolute frame of reference time"?**

Comment: There is no "absolute frame of reference", not even if you put it in scare quotes.

Comment: yes it is "where time has its maximum universal speed as time in deep space between Galaxy Filaments"

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this got VTCed as unclear or opinion based as it seems clear to me. If we have two synchronised clocks in Minkowski spacetime and a gravitational wave passes through the region containing one of the clocks but not the other do the clocks remain synchronised during and after the passing of the gravity wave?

Comment: @JohnRennie: The normal gravitational waves for LIGO are space-space strains and do not effect clocks. The Schwarzschild gravitational field from a static mass does a space-time strain and does effect clocks. The archive paper referenced by the OP calls the variation of the Schwarzschild metric as the source mass moves closer/farther a "gravitational wave". I don't see how the Center-of-Mass of two galactic BHs rotating about each other can change, though the Jan 2015 archive paper offers an equation for the strain as a function of distance and masses. Might be an interesting question?

Comment: @GaryGodfrey: the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00996 is essentially covering the situation I described above. The separation of the clocks means the wave reaches them at different (coordinate) times so the clocks can be compared when the wave has reached one clock but not the other.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I suspect the use of absolute reference time probably is some cause for the *unclear* votes.

Comment: @KyleKanos: maybe this is an example of the sort of question [you recently criticised](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/7222/1325). Perhaps I am applying my own interpretation to a question that is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I don't think this is too broad (which is what I was discussing in the meta post), I was just pointing out a possible basis for an unclear vote. Your first comment is my interpretation of the question as well.

Comment: @brucesmitherson For an observer traveling at... what speed?  At rest? At rest compared to what?  There's no such thing as being at absolute rest, so there's no such thing as an absolute reference frame, even in "flat" space far away from other massive disturbances

Answer (score 2):

Gravitational waves do cause fluctuations in clock rate. However, a gravitational wave as strong as you request would very strongly self-gravitate. It might even collapse into a black hole. By comparison, this is the level of time dilation one would experience hovering above a black hole at a distance about 1% of its radius.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got a answer from a professor Ulf Danielsson.
http://katalog.uu.se/empinfo?languageId=1&id=N94-1558_2&q=Ulf+Danielsson

He say that time fluctuate around the time of the position where the gravitational wave pass. 
So now the question remain. 
Can the general relativity theory mathematically describe a gravitational wave that make the time fluctuate let's say ten times faster and ten times slower?

Regards MagI