# Gravitational waves and Possible distortions in time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, gravitational-waves

Straight off, i know similar questions have been asked at [How close would you have to be to the merger of two black holes, for the effects of gravitational waves to be detected without instruments?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168274/how-close-would-you-have-to-be-to-the-merger-of-two-black-holes-for-the-effects)
and
[Gravitational waves and time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218221/gravitational-waves-and-time)
But, none of those questions had the proper answers i was looking for. One showed how close we had to be at the original event that caused the gravitational waves we recently detected for us humans to be able to sense it, and the other didn't give any good answer about anything. Here, I am asking How big would two black holes orbiting each other have to be so we humans, at a safe distance from the black hole with minimal danger of being sucked in, can sense the Gravitational waves? How would this event affect us ? would it distort space time, so it looked like time was freezing for a microsecond and unfreezing, or would it look like a physical wave was moving everything, similar to the S-waves  or P-waves in an earthquake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here, I am asking How big would two black holes orbiting each other have to be so we humans, at a safe distance from the black hole with minimal danger of being sucked in, can sense the Gravitational waves?

This depends not only on the masses of the black holes but also on how their orbit period has already decreased during inspiral. But if you would be close enough to sense the gravitational waves I dont't think you would be safe whatever "safe distance" means.

> How would this event affect us ? would it distort space time

Yes. Being sensitive enough you would feel tidal gravity due to Weyl curvature stretching and squashing you periodically.